# how do i print a vertex to the console in opengl?

Tags: opengl, vertex

It sounds ridiculous but I can not find any information on how can I print a vertex from a vertex array (from its corresponding GLuint) to the console?

I need to do this to help me debug an application.

Comment: i just need a way to get the individual x y z from the vertex?

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL doesn't know about stdio. So it boils down to reading the corresponding data from the vertex array, turn it into a string and print it using the usual functions.

If you're using a client side VA, then you already have all data in place. If you're using VBOs the simplemost method would be to map the VBO into client address space (glMapBuffer) and go from there as if it were a regular VA.

Comment: thanks man, yeh i get the process i just wondered how to get the values :)

Comment: @HarryPatrick you should clarify what you mean, then. As datenwolf said, "_[read] the corresponding data from the vertex array, turn it into a string and print it using the usual functions._"

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from a buffer with `glGetBufferSubData()`. For example, to get data from the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, use:

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, size, data);
```

where `offset` is the offset into the buffer, and `size` the amount of data you want to read, both in units of bytes.

Say if you want to read 256 bytes starting at 1K into the buffer:

```
GLubyte data[256];
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, 256, data);
```

An alternative is to use `glMapBuffer()`, or `glMapBufferRange()` in GL 3.0 or higher. Both of them return a pointer you can read from. For the same example as above:

```
GLubyte data[256];
GLvoid* pBufData = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, 256, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
memcpy(&data, pBufData, 256);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```